# SQL Server - Percentage Completion based on boolean values

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Scenario:**

I have a scenario where orders are either complete (1) or incomplete (0). I have 2 queries which can count orders that are complete/incomplete based upon the staff member who added them.

**Views:**

```
 CREATE VIEW CompleteOrdersView AS
 SELECT
 Staffname,
 COUNT(OrderComplete) AS OrdersComplete
 FROM OrderTable
 WHERE OrderComplete = 1
 GROUP BY Staffname

  CREATE VIEW InCompleteOrdersView AS
 SELECT
 Staffname,
 COUNT(OrderComplete) AS OrdersComplete
 FROM OrderTable
 WHERE OrderComplete = 0
 GROUP BY Staffname
```

**Problem:**

To compare this data with the 2 current views, this is going to mean I need to create a 3rd view, instead of 1. Is it possible to get both of these results into 1 view, and then perform the following 3 tasks:

1. A column which adds the Complete and In-Complete orders together, to give me **TotalOrders** based on the **Staffname**
2. Generate a Percentage Completion ratio based on the **Staffname**, **TotalOrders** and **OrdersComplete**
3. Generate a Percentage InComplete ratio based on the **Staffname**, **TotalOrders** and **InCompleteOrders**

**Table and Data:**

```
 CREATE TABLE OrderTable (OrderID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 Staffname VARCHAR (50),
 OrderComplete BIT)

 ALTER TABLE OrderTable ADD CONSTRAINT OrderID_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)

INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 0)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 0)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 0)

INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 1)
```

**Example Output from Problem above:**

```
Staffname    OrdersComplete    InCompleteOrders    TotalOrders     CompletePercentage   InCompletePercentage    
Joe Bloggs          7                  3                10                70%                  30%
```

Thankyou for your help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need so many views?  A simple query works:

```
SELECT Staffname, COUNT(*) as numOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN OrderComplete = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IncompleteOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN OrderComplete = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CompleteOrders,
       AVG(CASE WHEN OrderComplete = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as CompleteOrders_proportion
FROM OrderTable ot
GROUP BY staffname;
```

Comment: Ahh I didnt realize you can use SUM/AVG on CASE, that answer took a lot less time than it did to write out my question above haha, thankyou for that!! I shall accept in 10 minutes when it lets me

Comment: Great technique to hot-wire the percentages +1